# Remove gap after end of scrolling div

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I am trying to display series of div one after another.It is scrolling nicely, but after the last div gets out of the screen, then only the first div is coming in.But i need my first div immediately after the last div in scrolling without leaving any gap.

**My code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var delayb4scroll=1000
var marqueespeed=1
var pauseit=1 
var copyspeed=marqueespeed
var pausespeed=(pauseit==0)? copyspeed: 0
var actualheight=''

function scrollmarquee(){
  if (parseInt(cross_marquee.style.top)>(actualheight*(-1)+1))
    cross_marquee.style.top=parseInt(cross_marquee.style.top)-copyspeed+"px"
  else
    cross_marquee.style.top=parseInt(marqueeheight)+8+"px"
}

function initializemarquee(){
  cross_marquee=document.getElementById("vmarquee")
  cross_marquee.style.top=0
  marqueeheight=document.getElementById("marqueecontainer").offsetHeight
  actualheight=cross_marquee.offsetHeight
  if (window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Netscape/7")!=-1){ //if Opera or Netscape 7x, add scrollbars to scroll and exit
    cross_marquee.style.height=marqueeheight+"px"
    cross_marquee.style.overflow="scroll"
    return
  }
  setTimeout('lefttime=setInterval("scrollmarquee()",30)', delayb4scroll)
}

if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener("load", initializemarquee, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
  window.attachEvent("onload", initializemarquee)
else if (document.getElementById)
  window.onload=initializemarquee
</script>

<div id="marqueecontainer" onmouseover="copyspeed=pausespeed" onmouseout="copyspeed=marqueespeed">
    <div id="vmarquee" style="position: absolute; width:243px;">
    <?php include 'viewdata.php';?>
    </div>
```

**viewdata.php**

```
    <?php    
    mysql_connect(gethostbyname(trim(`hostname`)) , ****, ****) or die ("Please check your server connection."); 
    mysql_select_db("****") or die("error");
    $query = "select * from table1";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);
    $flags2=0;$flags=0;
    ?>
    <?php
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $flags++;
    ?>
    <div class="marqueeElement" style="height:auto;width:220px;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;color: #BF5A14;font-size:70%;position:absolute;padding-left:10px;"> 
    <br><br><font style="font-weight:bold;color:#003399;">col 1 </font>
    <br><font style="font-weight:bold;color:#003399;">col 2 </font>         
</div>
<div style="height:150px;margin-left:-40px;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;">---------------------------------------------------<br></div>
    <?php } ?>
<font style="margin-left:-40px;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;">---------------------------------------------------</font>
```

viewdata.php gets the data from table and print it to div

Comment: Would you be able to create a JSFiddle of your code?

Comment: Thank you Adsy for taking your time to go through my question. But i had found the solution by repeating the while loop in viewdata.php

Comment: Good news! You're best to put what you just said as an answer to your own question so if anyone else has the same problem then they will know how to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem to remove the blank space(Atleast does not show blank space to you for longer period of time until which you wont stay on that page ).

I just changed my viewdata.php

**viewdata.php**

```
<?php    
mysql_connect(gethostbyname(trim(`hostname`)) , ****, ****) or die ("Please check your server connection."); 
mysql_select_db("****") or die("error");
$query = "select * from table1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$num = mysql_numrows($result);
$flags2=0;$flags=0;$temp=400;
?>
<?php
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$flags++;   


 ?>
    <div class="marqueeElement" style="height:auto;width:220px;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;color: #BF5A14;font-size:70%;position:absolute;padding-left:10px;"> 
    <br><br><font style="font-weight:bold;color:#003399;">print col 1 </font>
    <br><font style="font-weight:bold;color:#003399;">print col 2 </font>         
</div>
<div style="height:150px;margin-left:-40px;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;">---------------------------------------------------<br></div>
    <?php } ?>

<?php 

//to start the loop if table have more than 3 rows 

if($num > 3) {

while($temp > 0) {
$temp--;
 $query2 = "select * from table1";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die (mysql_error());
    $num2 = mysql_numrows($result2);
 while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {   ?> 

 <div class="marqueeElement" style="height:auto;width:220px;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;color: #BF5A14;font-size:70%;position:absolute;padding-left:10px;"> 
    <br><br><font style="font-weight:bold;color:#003399;">print col 1 </font>
    <br><font style="font-weight:bold;color:#003399;">print col 2 </font>         
</div>
<div style="height:150px;margin-left:-40px;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;">---------------------------------------------------<br></div>


<?php  } } } ?>



<font style="margin-left:-40px;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;">---------------------------------------------------</font>
```